# Getting crash on menu button click on galaxy s2 (android 2.3.6) using ActionBarCompat (android-support-v7-appcompat)

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar-compat

Crash log :

```
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:543)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3598)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3678)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:457)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:423)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:47)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ListMenuPresenter.java:107)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.getListMenuView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:435)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreatePanelView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:305)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelView(ActionBarActivity.java:122)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:321)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:583)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1251)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2694)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2669)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1908)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
12-19 00:55:30.175: E/ACRA(531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: Bipin, did you ever solve this problem?